# Async PHP in Laminas Framework

Tags: php, asynchronous, laminas

I have a laminas-based php application that creates pdfs after a successful booking. The creation of the pdfs is pretty time-consuming.

Coming from java, I just thought, good. Create an async process for the pdf creation and return immediately. Unfortunately, that does not seem to be an easy task (at least for me).

Laminas itself has a middleware for async processing (https://docs.mezzio.dev/mezzio-swoole/v3/async-tasks/). But this seems way too big as a solution for my simple problem.

Now I tried to use Spatie like this:

```
$pool = Pool::create();

            $pool[] = async(function ($bookingId, $mandantId) {
                $bookingTable = $this->getTable('booking');
                $bookingTable->setMandantId($mandantId);
                $booking = $bookingTable->get($bookingId);

                $booking->sendStuff();
                return 2;
            });
```

Unfortunately, this creates a Serialization of 'PDO' is not allowed error. As far as I understood, the pdo is the db connection which can not be serialized to the async process.

Now I have no idea how to fix this. How can i use the same pdo? Should I inject and call another controller? Should I move the code away from the db-related classes? But the creation of the pdf requires data from the db and needs to save the result in the db as well.

Is the right approach? Did anyone do such a thing with laminas and how did you solve it?

Comment: Looks like the only problem you have is the serialization. Consider to create a task and create the objects you need in run(), Cf. https://github.com/spatie/async#working-with-tasks .Simulate with some sleep() or so so that you can find out if it matches your expectations (that you can do with the closure already, just remove the other code).